# GetSystemPath or SHGetSpecialFolderPath - Which do I use for CommonDocs folder?

Tags: delphi, windows-xp-sp2

(Delphi 2006) I am getting the Common documents folder in order to create another folder off it during my app startup.  This has been working fine - it always returns:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\
```

but I have just received a bug report from a Spanish user that includes a startup log that shows the app was trying to create:

```
MyApp\
```

instead of:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\MyApp\
```

i.e. the common docs folder string was empty.  The code to get this is:

```
function GetCommonDocumentsFolder : TFilename ;

begin
Result := GetSystemPath (CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS) ;
end ;
```

I also note in my researching of this problem that there is also a system call:

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPath
```

Which one should I be using?  GetSystemPath (CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS) has worked for me (at least in English locale Windows XP).

So 2 questions really, possibly related:

- why does GetSystemPath (CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS) return null?
- should I in fact be using SHGetSpecialFolderPath ?

(boy, this was a hard one to find tags for)

Source for the mysterious GetSystemPath:

```
function GetSystemPath (Folder: Integer) : TFilename ;

{   Call this function with one of the constants declared above. }

var
    PIDL    : PItemIDList ;
    Path    : LPSTR ;
    AMalloc : IMalloc ;

begin
Path := StrAlloc (MAX_PATH) ;
SHGetSpecialFolderLocation (Application.Handle, Folder, PIDL) ;
if SHGetPathFromIDList (PIDL, Path) then
    begin
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter (Path) ;
    end
else
    begin
    Result := '' ;
    end ;    ;
SHGetMalloc(AMalloc) ;
AMalloc.Free (PIDL) ;
StrDispose (Path) ;
end;
```

Comment: So, ultimately, you're asking whether the use an API function, or a library function that calls a different API function. That doesn't really matter — they both do the same thing. What you *should* be doing is checking the API function's return value so you know whether you have a valid path. Your library function unhelpfully returns an empty string instead of telling you that it couldn't do what you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28VS.85%29.aspx) when you want to know the path corresponding to a [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

I don't know what `GetSpecialFolderPath` is, I can't find it in my Delphi. Did you mean `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`? I also can't find `GetSystemPath`, but that doesn't change my answer!

Comment: I did mean SHGetSpecialFolderPath.  Thanks.  The reason why you couldn't find GetSystemPath is because (so I've just discovered) it's a routine I must have got from somewhere - I've added it to the question.  It probably answers the question - I imagine it's failing for some reason and returning a null string.  I guess SHGetSpecialFolderPath will do the job without failing under Spanish Windows XP.  My Bad.  (or more accurately, My Stupidity)

Comment: @ross That explains it. Just use SHGetSpecialFolderPath and all will be well!